# How to disable "header already sent" message on linux, cpanel?

Tags: linux, php, cpanel, whm, header

I building my sites on the localhost (runs wamp on windows), and when I upload it to my server, I always get 
"Cannot modify header information - headers already sent"

I understand that there shouldn't be any blank lines and everyhing, and usually this works out. but now I need to redirect someone after the header has been sent, how can I make my server act like my localhost ?

i'm using cpanel and WHM:

cPanel 11.25.0-R42399 - WHM 11.25.0 - X 3.9
CENTOS 5.4 x86_64 virtuozzo on vps

I will appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

In short, you need to prevent PHP from outputting anything to the browser before you get to the point where you want to use the header() function.

This should be done by careful programming practices, of which your 'no blank lines' is one, or by storing PHP's output in an output buffer, and only outputting when you're ready for it.

See the [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_flush()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) methods. You use ob_start() at the start of your application. This disables output and stores it into a buffer. When you're ready to start outputting, use ob_flush() and PHP will send the buffer's contents to the browser, including the headers that are set till that point. If you don't call ob_flush() then the buffer is output (flushed) at the end of the script.

The reason why it works on your WAMP development environment is most likely that output buffering is already enable by default in the php.ini. Quite often these all-in-one packages  enable a default buffer for the first 4k bytes or so. However, it is generally better to explicitly start and flush the buffer in your code, since that forces better coding practices.

Comment: ob_start does not buffer headers, just the content.

Answer (score 0):

Well,
I guess by more thinking and better programing you can manage to keep all redirects before any HTML is written.

This problem solved by the old rules...

Answer (score 0):

@user31279: The quickest and dirtiest way I know of is to use `@` to suppress the warning, so e.g.

```
@header('Location: some-other-page.php');
```